# Can't target DIVs on page

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems targetting the DIVs on this test page I made at http://flexibletheme.tumblr.com/

In particular I have a div with an id of columns (div#columns), I can't get the background color to change.

Any ideas on how to get the background to render in div#columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `#columns` to [clear the floats](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/).

Another common way to clear floats is the [clearfix class](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Take your pick of the two methods, but in general `overflow: hidden` is easier if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. How did you know that the floats were causing a problem?

Comment: I've seen the problem a million times before - I'd already guessed it  was this as soon as I saw "I can't get the background color to change" along with the name "columns". To verify, I used Google Chrome's Developer Tools, and inspected your `#columns` element and saw it had a height of `0px`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I didn't notice that DIVs have 0px when it wraps around the content?

Comment: They don't normally have a `height` of `0px`. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/n645G/

Answer (score 2):

In the source code on your page, you're missing a double-quote:

```
<div id=columns">
```

Try changing it to:

```
<div id="columns">
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that out, it was something to do with the overflow that was causing the problem.